# Error : Cannot execute this command because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html

When I try to run :
`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver1;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`

I get this error :
`Cannot execute this command because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed. Install the version of that package that matches the installed version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and try again.`

This is part of my project.json

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
```

Any ideas?
Peter

Comment: Try using the NuGet package manager to ensure it's installed.

Comment: Use nuget package to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and make sure it's the same version as `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: in Manaage Nuget packages, I manually added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design  (v1.0.0-preview2-final) to my project. .
Also , i already have this line in my project.jsaon :
       "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Core": "1.0.0-preview2-final"

Is there any other things I can check?

Comment: i get the same error following this tutorial : https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#blogging-database

Comment: which version for EFC does your .json point to?  1.0.1 or 1.0.0?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue I could not run add-migration from package manager console; it produced the same error. In my case lacking `"type": "platform"` for .netcore.app was the issue. I had to change

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
```

to

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App":
{
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
```

Then add to tools section

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install latest version `1.1.0`.That issue was on the `1.0.0-preview2-final`.

You can see the details on GIT : [**EFCore 1.1.0 Preview Final 1 Scaffold-DbContext Error**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6883)

Comment: so here is some of my project.json


    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

Comment: yes,you're using old frameworks.you must update it to latest version `1.1.0`.